# How to insert the data from one column into another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been struggling with this issue for some time at my job and I need some help.

I have 2 tables, one with a ton of information and other where part of the information should be, i need to move a single column to a table already created with some codes to identify every row that is going to be inserted (mostly users) and it throws an error because it says that I must insert an id also, but the id already are there.

let's say I have these tables:

```
table_information
admin_name|admin_address|admin_phone|admin_mail
john      |home         |111111111  |something@mail.com
pete      |house        |222222222  |else@mail.com
mike      |crib         |333333333  |my@mail.com
ryan      |someplace    |444444444  |custom@mail.com
daniel    |somewhere    |555555555  |user@mail.com
bruce     |anywhere     |666666666  |bruce@mail.com
dave      |everywhere   |777777777  |dave@mail.com


table_admin
admin_id|admin_name
1       |
2       | 
3       |
4       |
5       |
6       |
7       |
```

and I need to move the column of the user names to the table users that has the codes so the result must be something like this:

```
table_information
admin_name|admin_address|admin_phone|admin_mail
john      |home         |111111111  |something@mail.com
pete      |house        |222222222  |else@mail.com
mike      |crib         |333333333  |my@mail.com
ryan      |someplace    |444444444  |custom@mail.com
daniel    |somewhere    |555555555  |user@mail.com
bruce     |anywhere     |666666666  |bruce@mail.com
dave      |everywhere   |777777777  |dave@mail.com

table_admin
admin_id|admin_name
1       | john
2       | pete
3       | mike
4       | ryan
5       | daniel
6       | bruce
7       | dave
```

the information is coming from a big database (around 1500 rows) where the admin names are repeated, therefore I have been using the select distinct to filter some of the duplicate rows.

The way I've been doing it is like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_admin (admin_name)
SELECT DISTINCT admin_name FROM table_information
```

And i obtain this:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'admin_id' column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Also important is that the column `admin_id` from the table `table_admin` could not be identity (or auto increment) so the id's could not be automatically generated (I would have done it this way, but it's the way they work here).

Am I lacking something? doing something wrong? Let me know some suggestions, or solutions for this problem that is driving me crazy please.

Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: To ask an obvious question, we run out of unique single digits as soon as a fourth record appears.  Can you add more sample data so that we might see what you have in mind?

Comment: hi tim, i've edited the post with more examples so you can understand properly what i tried to explain, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'admin_id' column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The reason you get this error is because `admin_id` is not `NULLABLE` meaning you **must** have an `admin_id` for every row. When you perform an `INSERT` you must explicitly insert the `admin_id` since it isn't an `IDENTITY` property column.

Your expected results show that you want to do an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`. A `UPDATE` would `UPDATE` the `admin_id` currently in your `table_admin` table instead of inserting new rows. **The one thing that is unclear is how the `table_admin` relates to `table_information`**. How does john get assigned `admin_id = 1`?

Once you define that, here is the `UPDATE`

```
update t 
set t.admin_name = i.admin_name
from table_admin t
inner join table_information i on i.someColumn = t.someColumn
```

If you don't care which `admin_name` gets what `admin_id`, then you can create a surrogate key and update your table.  It would look like this:

```
select distinct 
    admin_name
    ,admin_id = row_number() over (order by (select null))
into #tempInformation
from table_information

--this is going to show the admin_id that will be updated in the table_admin table
select * from #tempInformation

update t 
set t.admin_name = i.admin_name
from table_admin t
inner join #tempInformation i on i.admin_id = t.admin_id
```

**EDIT**

If you don't have *any* `admin_name` currently populated in the `table_admin` then I suggest you just truncate that table and insert your distinct `admin_name`. Again, I would also make `admin_id` an identity property

```
truncate table table_admin

insert into table_admin (admin_id, admin_name)
   select distinct 
        admin_id = row_number() over (order by (select null))
        ,admin_name
```

I should highlight that in most schemas, the `admin_id` would mean something. It would be a `PRIMARY KEY` for this table and be used to relate this table to others in the database. Thus, not knowing which `admin_id` goes to which `admin_name` means you have a real mess on your hands and assigning them at random *should* break downstream processes... but that may not be the case since you haven't been keeping it up to begin with.

> the column admin_id from the table table_admin could not be identity

I'd ask why? This would allude to you have a mapping of the `admin_name` to `admin_id` already... but you haven't shown that.

Comment: Hi scsimon, the table_information is an example of an import of an excel document and the table_admin is where the information will definetly be for future queries, the information will be moved from the table table_information to another tables with the information of the columns i posted as example. in the other questin you had was "how john gets the number 1?" well, that was just an example of what the result should look like, i'll try out your answer and i'll tell you if it worked, thank you so much for your reply

Comment: @ZERO.... OK. Hope this was all clear, if not ask any questions you have. It should suffice, though.

Comment: also notice that the main idea of the admin_id is to identify every user, the table is supposed to be related by the column admin_name because they have matching values, later the table_information table will be deleted

Comment: Then `admin_id` isn't a surrogate key and is really pointless here since you aren't using it anywhere. This also means that admin_name would have to be unique to make sense. Anywho, good luck [and don't forget to read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for this post and future questions.

Comment: scsimon: the idea of the key is for further uses such as combining multiple table queries that i'll do later on, that is the use of that, i tried out your code and it worked half of that, the first half stored the names temporal table but the update isn't working so i can't move the names to the table to be related with the codes the error i encountered is that when you pass the information to the temporal table you passed the admin_id which is only on the admin_table as you see in the example

Comment: it actually works, but it wasn't the result i was looking for because it doesn't stores the names with the codes that are already generated in the table_admin, it showed the names with numbers that i didn't get where they came from, now having the names of the admins stored in a temporal table, how they can be moved to the table_admin table where they will be related to a respective code? thanks for your replies and contributions.

Comment: the id that a determined user gets is actually irrelevant but the main idea is that is not moving from time to time, and as i said in prior replies the admin_id will be used as PK for further queries i'll be doing later on, i treated the admin_name as an FK in this particular case i might be mistaken by doing that, i don't know, but now the question is: how do i move the names (that are the ones i need in that table) to actually move from the temporal table? sorry for being so clumsy

Comment: I showed you in my answer @Zero and gave multiple work arounds. Sorry, I can no longer help as your questions keep getting more unclear.